# Does the Banach space $( \ell ^2 \oplus \ell ^2 )$ have F.P.P?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

The space $( \ell^2 ,\lVert \cdot \rVert _2 )$  is a Hilbert space. The space 
 $X=(\ell^2 \oplus \ell^2 , \lVert \cdot \rVert_\infty )$ is a Banach space. Does X have fixed point property? (For any closed convex bounded subset $C\subseteq X $ and any nonexpansive map $T:C\to C $ there is a $x\in C$ such that $T(x)=x$)

The space $X$ isn't uniformly convex so I can't use theorems about uniformly convex. There is no theorems about F.P.P in products of spaces and I have no another idea. Does someone have any idea?

Comment: Maybe use (somehow) the fact that the norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ is the limit of uniformly convex norms $\|\cdot\|_p$ for $p\to\infty$?

Comment: No. this is not solution. I tried for ten days but i didn't achieve  solution

Comment: How is your norm defined? Is $$|| \,\cdot \,||_{\infty} = \max \left( || \,\cdot \,||_2, \; || \,\cdot \,||_2 \right)?$$

Comment: Yes .      .the norm is this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that the answer is *yes*, and that it should follow from the following facts:

1. every Hilbert space is uniformly convex, hence it has normal structure;
2. the direct sum of two Banach spaces with normal structure, endowed with the infinity norm, has again normal structure (Belluce-Kirk-Steiner, Pacific Journal Math. 1968);
3. the finite direct sum of separable Banach spaces (with any of the possible equivalent norm on it) is itself reflexive, in particular $X = \ell^2 \oplus \ell^2$ is reflexive;
4. normal structure on a reflexive Banach space implies FPP (Kirk,  Amer. Math. Monthly 1965).

Comment: But  normal structure implies  W.F.P.P   And I didn't see  number (3) somewhere.

Comment: Wouldn't WFPP and FPP coincide on reflexive spaces?

Comment: Yes. But X maybe isn't reflexive.

Comment: The finite direct sum of reflexive Banach spaces is itself reflexive. Note also that your norm is equivalent to the (finite) $L^p$-norm $$||(x, \, y)||_p = \left( ||x||^p + ||y||^p \right)^{1/p},$$
see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space#Reflexivity